# How to stop an audio/video in SharePoint using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, sharepoint-2010

I need to embed an audio in SharePoint 2010 and then stop it on click and run a new audio using a jQuery function. The issue is that my new video is playing but the old one is not stopping.
Below is my code:

```
<div id="page1">
<div align="left" style="float:left"><img src="/George-Washington-Story-Page-1.jpg"/></div>
<div style="width:50px" style="float:left"></div>
<div style="float:left; width: 14px;" id="topage2">next</div><br/>
<div >
<OBJECT class="Player" height="100" width="100" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
<PARAM name="autoStart" value="true"/>
<PARAM name="UIMode" value="full"/>
<PARAM name="URL" value="/George-Washington-1.wmv"/>

</OBJECT>
</div>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" NAME="BtnStop" VALUE="Stop" OnClick="ShutMeDown()">

</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#topage2').click(function(){
$('#page1').hide();
$('#page23').show();
$('.Player').attr('autoStart','false');
//var newElement = "<object width='250' height='250' type='application/x-mplayer2' classid='CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6'><param name='url' value='/George-Washington-3.wmv'><param name='filename' VALUE='/George-Washington-3.wmv'>
<PARAM name='autostart' VALUE='1'>
<param name='uiMode' value='full'><param name='autosize' value='1'><param name='playcount' value='1'>
<EMBED TYPE='application/x-mplayer2' src='/George-Washington-3.wmv' NAME='MediaPlayer' id='wmvViewer' autostart='true' WIDTH='250' HEIGHT='250' ShowControls='1' ShowStatusBar='0' ShowDisplay='0'></EMBED></OBJECT>";
//$("#testvoice").html(newElement);
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your object's classid refer to the windowMediaPlayer , so the control api like below:

var player = $(".Player")[0];

```
//stop
player.controls.stop();

//play
player.controls.play();

//change video
player.URL="xxx" ;
```

and more infomation in here http://hi.baidu.com/s_jinhui/item/48c878ab2bcf279d15107399

hope it can help you